# Receiving String from a ListView that is Included in a Layout. Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am making A Chat Application on Android.

These are some of the files

I'm trying to get the String(name) that is in the ListView. When I click the name, I want it to go to a new activity ChatBox. How would I get a String that the user clicks on? 
I attempted a few times in freindslist.java for method contactOnClick() I'm guessing I just have to fix that somehow to be able to function the way I want it to. Because, It seems as if the contactOnClick() isn't connected right with the ListView.

FriendsList.Java:

```
package com.example.swagmessenger5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FriendsList extends ListActivity {

    ListView listOfContacts;
    static String data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_list);

        //create string names
        String[] names = {"tim", "liz" , "ori" , "john" , "bryan","tim", "liz" , "ori" , "john" , "bryan","tim", "liz" , "ori" , "john" , "bryan" };
        //get online status boolean
        boolean[] status = {true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true, false, true,true, false, true, false, true };
        //they should be intertwined, meaning boolean lined up with string.


        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, names, status );
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    }



    public void contactOnClick(View view){ //go to chat box with the talker name on top
        //View myLayout = findViewById( R.id.lol );
        listOfContacts = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lol );  //need to et rigt text

        listOfContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
          {
             data = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        }});

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatBox.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }





      //** code to make arrays go forever can keep adding.
/*    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] series = {4,2};
            series = addElement(series, 3);
            series = addElement(series, 1);
        }

        static int[] addElement(int[] a, int e) {
            a  = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
            a[a.length - 1] = e;
            return a;
        } */


    public void addfriend(View view){ //go to add friend page
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddFriend.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.friends_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the layout with the include in it.
activity_friends_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/swag_plus"
        android:onClick="addfriend" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/swag_list"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        layout="@layout/activity_box_in_list_view"
        android:onClick="contactOnClick"
        android:id="@+id/lol" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

BoxInListView.java

```
package com.example.swagmessenger5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class BoxInListView extends ListActivity {

    //this is the friends list where it will inflate all the friends into the list veiw

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_in_list_view);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.box_in_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the file where the ListView is made. And this is the file that is being included into the friendslit xml.
activity_box_in_list_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is My ArrayAdapter
the array adapter is inflating in box_in_list_view
MyArrayAdapter.java

```
package com.example.swagmessenger5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private Context context;
      private String[] names;
      private boolean[] status;

      public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] names, boolean[] status) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_box_in_list_view, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names; //names in array
        this.status = status;   //names in status
      }


      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_box_in_list_view, parent, false);

        //Text view
        TextView nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);    //set id to text view variable
        ImageView onlineView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //set id to image view variable

        nameView.setText(names[position]);  //set textview(name) of the name in the right position

        // Check the status if online or offline
        boolean online = status[position];

        if (online)     //if online is true, the picture will be set to on
          onlineView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.button_onoff_indicator_on);
        else            //if online is false, the picture will be set to off
          onlineView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.button_onoff_indicator_off);

        return rowView;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an OnClickListener for the view inside getView in the adapter. Also, you can set the name to be the tag of the rootview to make things easier. Then you can have code like this in the OnClickListener:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    String name  = (String)v.getTag();
    doStuffWithName(name);
}
```

Comment: I agree, just a minor improvement: I'd add that you pass some listener to the constructor of the adapter that contains the method "doStuffWithName()", then the event can be processed at Fragment or Activity level.

Comment: I'm a beginner, how do I exactly set an OnClickListener for the view?

Comment: In getView() in the adapter, add:

rowView.setTag(names[position]);
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   String name  = (String)v.getTag();
                   doStuffWithName(name);    
                }
            });